# What are the Android libraries used?

Tags: android, dialog, android-library

I have seen a couple of these dialogs in different applications and wonder if there are some libraries I don't know about. Anyone knows libraries which provide these? They are really cool.

[image]
[image]
[image]

P.S. These three screenshots are taken from Expense Manager and Timely Alarm Clock.

Comment: Can you name the apps, it would be much easier to find the libraries. They are cool indeed :)

Comment: @Pius Go to this Link for Android Custom Views with cool UI:[Android Custom Cool UI](http://www.androidviews.net/)

Comment: @DheeB Added the names under the screenshots.

Comment: In this websites you can find all the Custom view and it's code from GitHub. If Useful +1 up

Comment: https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers